# are there any books on reactive extensions?

Tags: system.reactive

Someone asked this a year ago and there were none. Are there any now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Reactive-Extensions-Jesse-Liberty/dp/1430237473/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430237473)

Comment: I'm workin' on it! Gotta type faster

Comment: Oh, didn't notice it wasn't out yet.

Comment: @Paul Betts: It says delivery date: September 19th on my preorder, still. I'm going to guess that's not accurate?

Comment: Its OK now - you can go slow. THe new programming tools for windows seemed to be now based on some new technology called COM which probably has a different way of doing this kind of thing

Comment: You can get the PDF now on Apress Alpha program. That said the book is out in a few days

Comment: http://www.introtorx.com/